# Inverse of any element in a group of matrices

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I came across the following question in an under graduate course examination:

> Let $G$ be a group of all matrices of the form $  \pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}$, where $0\neq x\in \Bbb R$ under matrix multiplication. Find the inverse of any element in $G$.

It appears to me that the question is wrongly framed because any matrix of the given form doesn't have inverse due to the fact that its determinant is zero.

Comment: this is correct.

Comment: @Ahmad Bazzi Do you mean that the given question under consideration is correct?

Comment: Yes the question is correct as stated. The identity element of the group is not what you expect.

Comment: It is a group but with a different identity element than you first thought. hence the determinant argument does not disprove anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is that the identity element is not what you'd expect.

First, note that the group operation is clearly commutative. We can compute
$$\pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}\pmatrix{y&y\\y&y} = \pmatrix{2xy&2xy\\2xy&2xy}$$

which tells us that if $y=\frac{1}{2}$ (recall $x \neq 0$)

$$\pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}} = \pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}$$

So the identity element of this group is the matrix with $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

To compute the inverse, just look at the first expression again and write $2xy = \frac{1}{2}$, which gives  $y = \frac{1}{4x}$. Indeed, we can verify

$$\pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{4x}&\frac{1}{4x}\\\frac{1}{4x}&\frac{1}{4x}} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}}$$